# threadingを使って複数のウェブカメラからの動画を保存する方法

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera, 動画

2つのウェブカメラ(camera1, camera2)から得られる動画を、別々の動画ファイルとして保存したいです。それと同時に行わなければいけない処理がもう1つあったため(音楽を再生するもの、musicと定義)、threadingを使うことを考えています。
OpenCVのvideo.writeはメインスレッドで行わなければいけないと知り、毎フレームの情報をqueueで送ることを考えたのですが、カメラが2つあるせいなのか、あまり上手くいきません。下のコードは一応望み通りの動画ファイルが得られるのですが、camera1とcamera2の扱いが非対称で違和感・不安感があります(「###########」箇所参照)。
この後行う処理の都合上、二つの映像の毎フレームの時間をできるだけ同期させる必要があるため、それぞれの映像のキャプチャ〜書き込みまでを順番に繰り返すというのは避けたいです。
何か上手い方法はないでしょうか？ご教示いただきたいです。

#### 試したこと

- video1.writeとvideo2.writeを両方メインスレッド内で行う
- video1.writeとvideo2.writeを両方t_cameraスレッド内で行う
  →一応カレントディレクトリに動画ファイルは作られるが、読み取れない。
- camera1とcamera2のスレッドを分け、queueもcamera1用とcamera2用の2つ生成する
  →そもそもqを複数生成できない？
  →時間同期しづらい(Threading.EventやThreading.Conditionも試しましたが、精度は変わりませんでした)

**環境:**
Windows 10
Anaconda (Python 3.6)

#### コード

```
import time
import threading
import cv2
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import queue
import time
import asyncio

# VIDEO SETTING
camera1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
camera2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
fps1 = int(camera1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
w1 = int(camera1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h1 = int(camera1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fourcc1 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
video1 = cv2.VideoWriter('camera1.mp4', fourcc1, fps1, (w1, h1))
fps2 = int(camera2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
w2 = int(camera2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h2 = int(camera2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fourcc2 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
video2 = cv2.VideoWriter('camera2.mp4', fourcc2, fps2, (w2, h2))

frame_timing=[[],[]]
init_time=time.time()

# キュー生成
q = queue.Queue()

# thread内で行う処理(camera, music)定義
def camera(q):
    #base_time_0 = time.time()
    #duration_0 = 0
    while True:
        #now_time_0 = time.time()
        #duration_0 = now_time_0 - base_time_0
        #print(duration_0)
        #print(time.time())
        ret1, frame1 = camera1.read() # フレームを取得
        frame_timing[0].append(time.time()-init_time)
        ret2, frame2 = camera2.read()
        frame_timing[1].append(time.time()-init_time)
        cv2.imshow("camera1_side", frame1)
        cv2.imshow("camera2_top", frame2)
        video1.write(frame1)
        ########### video2.write(frame2) ###########
        q.put([frame1,frame2])
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            print("Ctrl+C")
            break

def music():
    time.sleep(10)
    # 適当に省略しました


# スレッド生成、開始
t_camera = threading.Thread(target=camera, args=(q, ))
t_camera.setDaemon(True)
t_music = threading.Thread(target=music)
t_camera.start()
t_music.start()

# cameraの続きの保存処理
base_time=time.time()
duration=0
while(duration<10):
    ############ video1.write(q.get()[0])###########
    video2.write(q.get()[1])
    now_time=time.time()
    duration=now_time-base_time

camera1.release()
camera2.release()
video1.release()
video2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 「OpenCVのvideo.writeはメインスレッドで行わなければいけないと知り」→情報源は何ですか？　`VideoWriter`はサブスレッド上でも生成でき、また`VideoWriter.write()`自体はサブスレッド上でも実行できるはずです（スレッドセーフティの確保はアプリケーション側の責務ですが）。一方、`imshow()`や`waitKey()`などはメインスレッド（メッセージループを持つUIスレッド）上で実行する必要があり、これらをサブスレッドから呼び出した場合の動作は未定義です。そのあたりを混同しているんじゃないですか？　また、コード中に突然出現している`frame_timing`や`init_time`は何者ですか？　投稿にあたって、まず「[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方 - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」を熟読してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。どこかのウェブサイトでそのような記述を見た気がしたのですが、おっしゃる通り、きっと混同して記憶してしまったんだと思います。また、frame_timingやinit_timeは単に前の版からの消し忘れでした。確認不足で申し訳ございません！経験不足ゆえ読みにくいコードと質問内容だったと思いますが、お手助けいただき本当にありがとうございます！

Comment: 提示したヘルプセンターのページはちゃんと読みましたか？　謝ったり言い訳をしたりする前に質問文を見直して、最低限ミスを修正・訂正するぐらいの努力はしましょうよ。

Comment: すみません、このような質問サービスを使ったのが初めてだったので、もうこの話は終わったものかと思っていました！質問の方修正しました。また、自力で解決策を見つけたのでそれも書いておきます。

Answer (score 1):

video.write()はスレッド内でも行うことができますが、スレッドを開始する前に

```
camera1.release()
camera2.release()
video1.release()
video2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

が行われてしまっており、カメラからの入力を読み取れていなかったために、再生不可能なファイルが生成されてしまっていたようです。
よって、この前にt_music.join()を入れることで解決しました。